# xbee serial module and minicom

Tags: linux, serial-port

When we connect a serial xbee module board to a Linux PC serially using RS232 9 pin cable, the data received on minicom screen is unreadable or sometimes no data is received at all. The setting is as follows:
baud rate : 9600
flow control: none
data bit: 8
parity: none
stop bits: 1
What possibly could be the reason of receiving such unreadable data on minicom?

Comment: What are you expecting from it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm seeing online a lot of the time garbled or a lack of content can be down to a number of different factors including:

- possibly incorrect baud rate. It seems as though despite what is said 
  http://cpham.perso.univ-pau.fr/WSN/XBee.html
- there have been some indications that some serial communication programs can send junk characters which cause the device to not communicate properly. Your best bet is to simply try another program
- possibly referencing an incorrect device file
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143989/minicom-and-xbee-module-no-feedback
- oddities in the way Linux deals with these devices as opposed to Windows. Based on what I'm reading you may need to do undergo a low level initialisation procedure to get it working correctly (think AT command set for modems) with minicom 
  http://www.digi.com/support/forum/5805/serial-communication-problem-with-xbee-series-01

If all else fails you could try running a serial communication program under Wine or else Windows under a Virtual Machine in Linux to communicate with it?